# Typed array for storing objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I have been using typed arrays like [Int32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Int32Array) in javascript. I want to implement a circular queue using javascript and don't want to compromise on performance.

The problem is that the queue items are of Javascript  `Object` type and so I can't save them in the simple `Array` object. Thus I need a Typed Array which can perform really well with JS `Object` type objects.

Regards.

**Update:**
From the comments it seems like people are not clear about the performance benefits of having a typed array so I created this js perf test to make is more apparent

http://jsperf.com/typed-array-vs-normal-array

Comment: Seriously? JS objects are what the normal array stores best.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `Array` is an Object in JavaScript.

Comment: `new Array(window,document,String);` works just fine - what made you think objects can't go in an array - is this regarding a particular implementation?

Comment: Wasn't even aware of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Int32Array implementation.

Comment: Performance is the key here. typed-arrays were 10 times faster in my case. Normal arrays are using hash keys and thus are not that effective

Comment: No they are not, and it's incredibly hard to make a correct and fair benchmark unless you are intimately familiar with engine internal specifics

Comment: @Tushar What data are you dealing with that needs that level of optimisation? Standard arrays are typically very fast. If you're experiencing majorly noticable performance issues, I'd have to question how you've got to this requirement

Comment: Long story short: There are no such typed arrays.

Comment: The reason typed arrays perform well (with my loose C++ knowledge) is because they can allocate a continuous block of "intsize * arraysize" bytes in memory. Objects take up "?????" bytes in memory, so no optimizations to make there.

Comment: There is a point, not because of the "TypedArray" but that the JavaScript object arrays are not quaranteed to be dense, or non-hashed, and he wants dense arrays.

Comment: The question makes a lot of sense, and it would be great if there was some ObjectArray which stored object references. When executing code that is intensive on array manipulation, JavaScript is orders of magnitude slower than the rest of languages that have real arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Typed arrays are there for efficiently storing primitive values. They are not based on a mechanism which magically improves performance. It is fast because it knows the type and the length of the stored value. "Object" is the base "type" in JavaScript. It's like the interface{} in go. You don't know too much about the "object" to store it efficiently. Therefore a typed array for an object can't exist by definition.

Comment: Well it can, the optimization is just not done. Knowing the fixed layout of dynamic objects is what all engines do as a necessity to even compete.

Comment: I agree with you but I also think that the main cause for a normal array to be slow is that it uses HASHs to find an element. HASHES always have a performance hit if you simply want to iterate over a list

Comment: @Tushar that is false, unless you do something really funky with your array, it will be backed by normal "C array"-like construct.

Comment: @Esailija could you explain why is there such a difference in performance in the jsperf link that I have shared in my question?

Comment: You need a data contract to use the c array. Objects, lacking such a contract, would need to use a mechanism much less efficient to use a "C Array". There has to be a waste. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7799543/300011 . JIT compilers can make a statical analysis of the code to reduce those inefficiencies but I don't think it can ever be as efficient.

Comment: @Tushar it is creating array and methods in the test loop. See this http://jsperf.com/typed-array-vs-normal-array/4. This tests access speed (which is about same in V8 since it can optimize pure int arrays even if they are not typed). You should specify numbers of your application and what it does.

Comment: @Esailija You just have 3 access to the array. Consider my case where there are 10,000,000 accesses to the array

Comment: @Tushar the test performs as much accesses as it can for 5 seconds. In this case it did 3,000,000,000 (5 seconds * 200 million per second * 3)

Comment: @Esailija But you are accessing the same element every time. In that case they are going to perform almost equally. See the difference if you may. Where are typed arrays are 94% faster if you are accessing a different element everytime.

Comment: @Tushar I am telling you it doesn't matter at all. See edit http://jsperf.com/typed-array-vs-normal-array/4